# I am not able to get rid off index.php from my URL ? I'm running Apache/2.4.25 (Win64) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 for PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php

I have done following steps:

1. I edited C:\Program Files\NetMake\v9\components\apache\conf\httpd.conf and I removed # form LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so in http.conf file.
2. I edited application/config/config.php as:
   $config['index_page'] = '';
3. I edited .htaccess file:
4. Finally I restarted the apache server.

But it still does not work. I still have to add index.php in URL as 
http://127.0.0.1:8090/Directory/sub-directory/index.php/authentication/login

Comment: I'd be good to mention which PHP framework you're using.

Comment: PHP Version 7.0.15
System 
Windows NT MOBINYASIN-PC 10.0 build 18362 (Windows 10) AMD64 
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with SourceGuardian v11.0.6, Copyright (c) 2000-2016, by SourceGuardian Ltd.

Comment: The Solution for Zend is:

Apparently all you need to do is replace this line:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
With this:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1
Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this guide to solve your problem:

http://acmeextension.com/remove-index-php-in-your-codeigniter-project/

Comment: Appreciate your help but the problem was Zend Framework, syntax settings in .htaccess file was just missing a ? mark in RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1

Comment: But for some reason now I'm having problem with images. Browser does not display images now.

Comment: Had to really understand and play with the settings in .htaccess file for Zend Framework, which has different settings for .htaccess file as compare to Xampp or Wamp.